# Configuration for Smart Group Cache

Tags: smartgroups

I have a very simple use case for Smart Groups. I have only two small Smart Groups that are both used exclusively for bulk mailings, once or twice per month:

1. All Individual Contacts: approximately 800 contacts
2. All Current Members: approximately 80 contacts

From what I've read, I'm thinking I probably don't need caching. Is it safe to disable the Rebuild Smart Group Cache scheduled job and set the Smart group cache timeout to 0?

Answer (score 1):

I would say yes. Although it probably does no real harm to have it on if you are not hammering it